# Django authentication serializer

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

In my app I use auth0 to do authentication. Everything works great, I can see new users being created in admin panel etc, but there is one issue.

When I go to my endpoint that displays data I have an empty list. Like this:

```
{
    "id": "d458196e-49f1-42db-8bc2-ee1dba438953",
    "owner": 1,
    "name": "dsdsds",
    "viewable": []
}
```

The list viewable is a list of users that can view the data object. So if you want to share your data with your friend you just add his email.

Like I said previous. This list is viewable form django admin level and drf form level but not in JSON. **How to display this data**?

Models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.conf import settings

class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class WalletInstance(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='owner', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    viewable = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='can_view', blank=True)
```

Settings.py:

```py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'budget_app.User'

SOCIAL_AUTH_TRAILING_SLASH = False
SOCIAL_AUTH_AUTH0_DOMAIN = '####'
SOCIAL_AUTH_AUTH0_KEY = '####'
SOCIAL_AUTH_AUTH0_SECRET = '####'
SOCIAL_AUTH_AUTH0_SCOPE = [
    'openid',
    'profile',
    'email'
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = {
    'social_core.backends.auth0.Auth0OAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
}

LOGIN_URL = '/login/auth0'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

Serializers.py:

```py
class WalletInstanceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.id')
    class Meta:
        model = WalletInstance
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update [@TeRe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7012095/tere) answer. The **settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL** is a string, it has no attribute objects. You can use **get_user_model** [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model):

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class WalletInstanceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.id')
    viewable = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=get_user_model().objects.all(), many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = WalletInstance
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class WalletInstanceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.id')
    viewable = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.objects.all(), many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = WalletInstance
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

Comment: when I'm runnig this code I get AttributeError: **'str' object has no attribute 'objects'**